# Using function inside CASE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use the `SUBSTR` and `NVL` functions inside the case. The case is in the where clause of the select statement.

The code below gives the following error:

> **ORA-00905**: missing keyword

```
AND ( CASE
        WHEN SUBSTR(upper(p_open_invoice),1,1) = 'Y' THEN
          NVL(P.AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING,0) = 0
        ELSE
          1=1
      END)
```

This looks like a syntax error around equal operator of `NVL` function.

Comment: Can you show us the full `SQL` statement? Are you running this from a script file? What is the goal in this `SQL`? Can you change the title to ask a question? Please refer to the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

That is not how `case` expressions work (in Oracle) -- there is no boolean type to return.

The simplest method is to remove the `case and express this as simple logic:

```
AND (SUBSTR(upper(p_open_invoice), 1, 1) <> 'Y' OR
     COALESCE(P.AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING, 0) = 0 
    )
```

If `p_open_invoice` can be `NULL`, you need to take that into account as well.

Comment: what can be done if there are too many conditions to be checked like in the below scenario:
--
--
AND (  CASE WHEN p_trx_date_low Is Null and p_trx_date_high Is Null Then
   a.trx_date = a.trx_date
   WHEN p_trx_date_low Is Not Null and p_trx_date_high Is Null Then
  a.trx_date >= p_trx_date_low
   WHEN p_trx_date_low Is Null and p_trx_date_high Is Not Null Then
  a.trx_date <= p_trx_date_high
 WHEN p_trx_date_low Is Not Null and p_trx_date_high Is Not Null Then
  a.trx_date between p_trx_date_low and p_trx_date_high
  End CASE)

Comment: @ChethanVishal . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have another question then you should ask it as a *new* question.  That said, `case` is rarely desirable in a `where` clause; the conditions can usually be expressed using `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `collation` as a result for `case..when` statements, it's better converting the condition to

```
AND (( SUBSTR(upper(p_open_invoice),1,1)  = 'Y' AND NVL(P.AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING,0) = 0 ) 
    OR SUBSTR(upper(p_open_invoice),1,1) != 'Y' )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're accustomed to programming in PL/SQL you may have seen that there's a BOOLEAN type in PL/SQL. However, this is not true in the Oracle database itself. The way I usually work around this is to use character expressions which return 'Y' or 'N' instead of `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Keeping this in mind - if you really want to use a CASE expression similar to what you had originally you can use the following:

```
AND CASE
      WHEN SUBSTR(upper(p_open_invoice),1,1) = 'Y'
        THEN CASE
               WHEN NVL(P.AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING,0) = 0 THEN 'Y'
               ELSE 'N'
             END
      ELSE 'Y'
      END = 'Y'
```

Here the CASE expression returns either 'Y' or 'N', which is then compared with 'Y'.